# RStudioにおいてRで計算した表をxtable関数を使って出力しコンパイルした時のエラー

Tags: r, latex

超初心者です。RStudioで作った表を楽に出力するために、TeXの勉強をはじめました。
（TeX live2017で、RStudioはVersion 1.0.136です。）
RStudioを使っています。Rで計算した表をxtable関数を使って出力し、TeXで
コンパイルをしようと考えました。下記のコードをうち、TeXコードを出力し、２．のようにSourceに貼り付けてコンパイルしたら、

> The font　size command\ normal size is not defined:

のエラーが２つと

> Environmental table  undefined
>   begin{document}is ended by \end{table}
>   This file needs 'pLaTeX2e'

とでてきています。
R StudioのGlobal OptionのSweaveの項目のtype setはXeLaTeXになっていますが、
pLaTeX2eの選択肢はないです。
何から勉強して解決していけばよいでしょうか？

１．Rのコード

```
> ans<-table(newvariable$bq6_2)
> p.ans<-round(ans*100/sum(ans),1)
> cbind(ans,p.ans)
ans p.ans
hh_under18  659  21.2
hh_over65   857  27.6
hh_others  1592  51.2
> table1<-cbind(ans,p.ans)
> tb1<-xtable(table1)
> print(tb1)
% latex table generated in R 3.4.0 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Jun 28 21:25:29 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\hline
& ans & p.ans \\ 
\hline
hh\_under18 & 659.00 & 21.20 \\ 
hh\_over65 & 857.00 & 27.60 \\ 
hh\_others & 1592.00 & 51.20 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
>
```

2.TeXのコード

```
\documentclass[11pt]{jsarticle}
\begin{document}
% latex table generated in R 3.4.0 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Jun 28 21:25:29 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\hline
& ans & p.ans \\
\hline
hh\_under18 & 659.00 & 21.20 \\
hh\_over65 & 857.00 & 27.60 \\
hh\_others & 1592.00 & 51.20 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: まずは jsarticle を article に変更してみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます。articleにすると、コンパイルできるのですが、これから幾つか表を作っていくなかで日本語も含む予定です。それでも｛article｝で大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: 質問とサンプルコードを修正されるのがよいと思います。ご質問の趣旨は、RStudio のLaTeXエディターで日本語を含むファイルをコンパイルしたい、ということであって、R や `xtable()` とは今のところ関係ないのではありませんか？

Comment: そうなりますね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

### 何から学ぶか

> 何から勉強して解決していけばよいでしょうか？

これがご質問の趣旨であれば，解答は簡単です。R のコードを入れる前に日本語に対応した LaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX 等の使い方を勉強するのがいいと思います。

R/RStudio の問題なのか LaTeX一般の問題なのか，日本語LaTeXに特有の問題なのかを切り分けることができるようになれば，自分で答えを見つけられる可能性を高めますし，自分では分からなくても回答を得られる可能性が上がります。答える側のハードルが下がりますし，適切なコミュニティにリーチしやすくなるので。

`documentclass` に何を入れるかについては，RStudio に特有の問題ではありますが，RStudio 上で完結したい場合には platex + dvipdfmx を使ったコンパイルは面倒なので, jsarticle クラスは避けたほうがよいです。

> Rで計算した表をxtable関数を使って出力し、TeXで
>   コンパイルをしようと考えました。下記のコードをうち、TeXコードを出力し、２．のようにSourceに貼り付けてコンパイル

R で生成したテーブルを LaTeX のソースにコピペするよりももっとよい方法があります。

1. LaTeX の機能を最大限使いたい場合は R Sweave を使う
2. テーブルを埋め込む程度であれば R Markdown 形式を用いる

いずれにせよ [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/) パッケージについて学ぶことになります。LaTeX の組版のフルパワーが必要ないのであれば [こちら](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) を参考に R Markdown の書き方を学ぶとよいです。HTML 出力等他の形式への出力にも対応しています。

個人的には，複雑な組版を使う場合には R Sweave（Rnw 形式），簡単な組版で事足りる（多くの場合はそうです）ときは R Markdown で pandoc のオプションを調べつつ使っています。

### R Markdown サンプル

R Markdown で日本語文書にR で生成した表を入れるには，次のようなファイルを作り，`.Rmd` という拡張子で保存します。RStudio で開くと Knit ボタンが見えるはずなので，これを押すと日本語とRの出力が混在したPDFが生成されるはずです。（IPAex フォントがインストールされていない場合は配布元の指示に従ってインストールする http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp）

````
---
title: サンプル
author: 名前
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%Y/%m/%d")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: no
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    template: null
    toc: no
documentclass: bxjsarticle
classoption: 
  - xelatex
  - ja=standard
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
```

# 表の出力

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
# ここに表を生成するコードを書く
# このサンプルでは，R に組み込みの pressure データを利用
xtable::xtable(pressure)
```
````

Comment: ありがとうございます。IPAex フォント、今リンク先に飛んでみましたが、これはRStudioからダウンロードするのでしょうか？実は冒頭の問題は、R markdownでやろうとして、```の部分を除いたコードを書いて質問しました。Outputのところに書くべき内容が全然違っていたようなのですが、RStudioのオリジナルの設定ではだめで加えていかなければということですね。このあたりのことはLatexの使い方を学べば一緒にわかるようになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 私のコードをそのまま使ってknit できず、かつその理由がフォント関連のエラーだったという前提の上でですが、フォントはリンク先の指示に従ってインストールしてください。

Comment: コメント欄で質問の真意を聞いてコメント欄で回答してしまうと、同じ問題を抱えてる人がここにたどり着いても自分には関係がないと思ってしまう可能性が高いです。コメント欄を時系列に並べて追いかけるようなことはしないと思うので。質問を改善していただけませんか？その後、回答を修正します。

Comment: 質問を改善とは、新規で投稿すればよいということでしょうか？「何から学ぶか」で別のツリーができているようなのですが。あまりわかっておらずすみません。

Comment: 「編集」というボタンがあるのでそこをクリックして編集していただければよいです。別のツリーができているように見えているのは， pote さんがゴールを明確にしていないと僕が考えており，その結果回答を１つに絞ることができなかったからです。

Comment: 他の方も回答してくださっていてツリーが3つくらいできていますが、それぞれ残すような形でやるにはどうすればよいのでｈそうか？

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージを見ると，使おうとしている処理系がファイルの内容に対応してない，という感じでしょうか．
質問を読むとRStudio からXeLaTeXでコンパイルしているようなので，documentclass を `jsarticle` から `bxjsarticle` に変えてください．

また，元のコードの

1. アンダーバー `_` をエスケープして `\_` にする
2. 行の末尾の `\` を `\\` にする

の2点を修正する必要がありますが，xtable の出力はここはきちんと整形してくれるので，投稿時のコピペミスかなと思います．

xtable の出力はこうなります．

```tex
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Fri Jul 07 00:45:59 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & ans & p.ans \\ 
  \hline
hh\_under18 & 659.00 & 21.20 \\ 
  hh\_over65 & 857.00 & 27.60 \\ 
  hh\_others & 1592.00 & 51.20 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

元のコードのまま（`jsarticle` を使う）場合は，`platex` を使うことになるので，RStudio からではなくコマンドプロンプト（もしくは ターミナル）から

```tex
platex hoge.tex
dvipdfmx hoge.dvi
```

という感じでコンパイルしてください．

Comment: ありがとうございます。そのままコピペをしているのでミスはないと思います。あまりに初心者で、上記修正すべき2点の意味がわからないのですが、コードの入力のときに、何かを変えるということなのでしょうか？
この出力をした時のコードをお示しいただけると大変ありがたいです。

Comment: 修正するのはTeX ファイルの`documentclass`だけです．修正点ですが，今見たら質問文の方が編集されて正しく見えていますね．どうやらコード記法にせずにソースコードを貼り付けられていたので`\\`が表示されていなかったようです．

Comment: そうなのですね。ありがとうございます。コード記法というのは、ここに載せるためのルールのようなものでしょうか。

Comment: ここの投稿は Markdown という書式です．コード記法というのはMarkdownの記法のひとつで，質問のときにサンプルコードを載せる際には正確に伝えるためにコード記法にしてください．具体的にはスペース4つで字下げします（質問を書くときに下に出ているプレビューが変わるはずです）．詳しくは[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)を．

Comment: ありがとうございます！承知しました。